# Python OpenCV application failed to convert into .exe on windows 10

Tags: python, c++, opencv, dll, py2exe

I am using Python-2.7 with py2exe-0.6.9 win 32 version. I have developed a tkinter GUI having OCR recognition program using openCV-3.1.0 and OpenTesseract (Pytesser) engine. I tried a lot to convert my program into an `.exe` but failed every time.

I have already installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 runtime, copied msvcp90.dll as well as Microsoft.vc90.crt.manifest into Python DLL folder but nothing worked at all. You can see the error below.

```
Error: C:\Python27>python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe
*** searching for required modules ***
*** parsing results ***
creating python loader for extension '_ctypes' (C:\Python27\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd -> _ctypes.pyd)
creating python loader for extension '_testcapi' (C:\Python27\DLLs\_testcapi.pyd -> _testcapi.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'win32pipe' (C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\win32pipe.pyd -> win32pipe.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'select' (C:\Python27\DLLs\select.pyd -> select.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'unicodedata' (C:\Python27\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd -> unicodedata.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'PIL._imaging' (C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.pyd -> PIL._imaging.pyd)
creating python loader for extension '_tkinter' (C:\Python27\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd -> _tkinter.pyd)
creating python loader for extension '_hashlib' (C:\Python27\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd -> _hashlib.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'bz2' (C:\Python27\DLLs\bz2.pyd -> bz2.pyd)
creating python loader for extension '_ssl' (C:\Python27\DLLs\_ssl.pyd -> _ssl.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'cv2' (C:\Python27\cv2.pyd -> cv2.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'pyexpat' (C:\Python27\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd -> pyexpat.pyd)
creating python loader for extension '_socket' (C:\Python27\DLLs\_socket.pyd -> _socket.pyd)
*** finding dlls needed ***
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll'
```

My setup.py script is:

```
# creating executable here
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append("py2exe")

setup(
    options = {"py2exe": {"bundle_files": 3,"compressed":"True"}},
    console=["gui_test3.py"],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

Comment: I've added code formatting to your logs/code - please do this in the future, to make things readable! Thanks.

Comment: @halfer thanks for the formatting